# Core data relation with predicates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship, nspredicate

I have an entity `Car` and an entity `Race`. Both entities has an attribute called `carClass`. My problem is that I want to create a relation between them on joining by `carClass`.

Basically I want to create a relation in core data which will represents the possible competitors of a race, depending on `carClass`, in other words if I create a race with a specific `carClass` and I call `competitors` on that race I want to get a list of cars with the same `carClass`.

My question is, is this possible to create using `Core Data relations`, I'm thinking about just adding an `NSPredicate` to a relation.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I think i didn't explained clearly what I want to achieve.

```
Car{
  carClass:string
}

Race{
 carClass:string
 competitors<-->>cars.carClass == carClass
}
```

And the `competitors` should be fetched automatically, so I don't have to add manually the competitors, he should retrieve all the matching cars from the cars model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest model would look something like this:

```
CarClass{
    name:string
    race<-->Race.carClass
    cars<-->>Car.carClass
}

Car{
    name:string
    carClass<<-->CarClass.cars
}

Race{
    name:string
    carClass<-->>CarClass.race
}
```

Don't think about this is SQL terms, think of it in object terms. Each entity should represent a real-world object, event or condition that you want to simulate. The relationships between objects should be mimic the real-world relationships. If both the `Race` and `Car` real-world things have a common relationship with a `CarClass` condition then you simply put that in the model.

Unlike SQL, object models can be arbitrarily complex and they can contain behaviors as well. Your not just stuck with tables, columns and rows.

### Update:

(*See update in OP for reference*)

***When you find yourself putting the same attribute value in two or more different entities, that usually means you need to create a new entity to model that value.***

In this case, even though in terms of data the carClass value is just a string ***logically*** it is separate thing altogether that is related to both `Race` and `Car` objects. So, to accurately model it, you need to provide a separate entity for it. In addition, you need to model competitors so you need a model that looks something like:

```
CarClass{
    class:string
    race<-->Race.carClass
    cars<-->>Car.carClass
}

Car{
    name:string
    carClass<<-->CarClass.cars
    competitor<-->>Competitor.car
}

Race{
    name:string
    carClass<-->CarClass.race
}

Competitor{
  name:string
  car<-->Car.competitor
}
```

(Note that this model assumes that all races are defined by their carClass and not the individual vehicles or drivers.)

So, to find all competitors of a particular race, you would walk `Race.carClass.cars.competitor`.

This probably isn't exactly what you want but you can get the idea or how you use entities and relationships to model real-world objects, events or conditions and the linkages between them.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I updated my question because I think I didn't explained my problem well. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly I have to create a class called `carClass` instead of using just a string, and I have to create a relation with the `Car` class, and also with the `Race` class. Then use `Race.carClass.cars` to get the list of cars from that `carClass`.

Comment: Yes, that will tie all the data together logically. Of course, you actual model maybe different in detail but you get the idea. When the same value shows up in two existing entities, and you find yourself fetching both based on that value, then the value probably needs its own entity and relationships.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible. But why not just check each cars carClass when you're setting up the race and add the car to the race if the class matches?

Comment: Too much cases are required to handle. What if I add more cars after a race is created? I have to add them manually again. Also this solution it not really consistent. But if you can show me a proof concept doing like this, I will be happy. Thanks.